# change xaxis range in plot

Tags: matlab, label

```
clear all
depth1 = [0;2;3;4;5;6;8;10;12;14;16;18];
depth2 = [0;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12];
depth3 = [0;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18;20;22;24];
Depth = {depth1,depth2,depth3};

data1 = [0.8,0.797,0.796,0.795,0.795,0.795,0.797,0.798,0.8,0.802,0.803,0.802];
data2 = [0.764,0.752,0.743,0.745,0.746,0.736,0.710,0.656,0.584,0.574,0.577,0.601];
data3 = [0.760,0.750,0.745,0.714,0.593,0.354,0.257,0.272,0.295,0.327,0.368,0.379];
Data = {data1;data2;data3}';

coloring = {[0 0 0],[1 0 0],[0 0 1]}';
marking = {'+','o','s'};

for i = 1:length(Depth);
    fh = figure(1);
    plot(Depth{i},Data{i},'color',coloring{i},'Marker',marking{i});hold on;
    legend;
    set(fh,'color','white');
    set(gca,'TickLength',[.01 .01],'TickDir','out','box','on','XMinorTick','on',...
        'YMinorTick','on','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize', 14,...
         'Fontweight','demi','XColor','k','YColor','k');      
end
```

This example shows a plot with three different variables measured at different depths, where the depth of each measurement varies. I am wondering if it is possible to change the xaxis so that the range shown varies from 0 to 1 which represent the minimum and maximum depths respectively. Is this possible?

The current method that I have used is:

```
newDepth = cellfun(@(x)linspace(0,1,length(x)),Depth,'un',0);
```

and then plot the data against this new depth vector.

```
for i = 1:length(Depth);
    fh = figure(1);
    plot(newDepth{i},Data{i},'color',coloring{i},'Marker',marking{i});hold on;
    legend;
    set(fh,'color','white');
    set(gca,'TickLength',[.01 .01],'TickDir','out','box','on','XMinorTick','on',...
        'YMinorTick','on','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize', 14,...
         'Fontweight','demi','XColor','k','YColor','k');      
end
```

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are normalizing the variables the wrong way. The current normalization of x-axis values using `cellfun(@(x)linspace(0,1,length(x)),Depth,'un',0);` degenerates the relationship among the elements of each `depth` vector. I think, the correct method will be,

```
 newDepth = cellfun(@(x)(((x)-(min(x)))'./((max(x))-(min(x)))'),Depth,'un',0);
```

This way, the relative spacing amongst the different elements of un-normalized `depths` are preserved in the normalized values as well. Use this, and let me know. I am certain the normalized graphs obtained using `newDepth = cellfun(@(x)linspace(0,1,length(x)),Depth,'un',0);` were incorrect. You just didn't realize it because the minor wrong scaling didn't manifest itself very starkly in the normalized graphs.

As for the method for plotting the graphs in loop, I find it fine at the moment. What exactly do you find wrong with it ?